# Why is the "odbc_connect" PHP function undefined in XAMPP for Linux?

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on a linux machine (RHEL 5), and the XAMPP is working fine

However, when I execute a test script containing the `odbc_connect` function, an error message is displayed:

```
call to undefined function (fatal error)
```

I had used the `phpinfo` function to see the configuration options, but it did not included anything related to odbc.  UnixODBC is already installed on the system.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please can you post what the fatal error says.

Comment: Already checked extensions in php.ini and added extension=odbc.so, then to it's not working, even it extensions directory I am not able to find odbc.so

Comment: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Test/DSNScript.php on line 48